# Should I declare a variable in class private when it is used in more than one function scope?

Tags: c++, qt

Let's say I have three methods here:
**Method 1:**

```
void function_1() {
    QString("%1").arg(QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy"));
}
void function_2() {
    QString("%1").arg(QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy"));
}
```

Because I may have to replace more than one argument, then the line will be really long, to make the functions more readable, I used the Method 2:
**Method 2:**

```
void function_1() {
    QString currentDate = QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy");
    QString("%1").arg(currentDate);
}
void function_2() {
    QString currentDate = QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy");
    QString("%1").arg(currentDate);
}
```

But I have noticed that in many of my functions needed to use `QString currentDate`, even though some people say `Variables should be declared as locally as possible`, if I do this, which means I have to write the same code in each function. So should I use method 3 instead to set `QString currentDate` in `class private`.
**Method 3:**

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        currentDate = QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy");
    }
private:
    QString currentDate;
    void function_1() {
        QString("%1").arg(currentDate);
    }
    void function_2() {
        QString("%1").arg(currentDate);
    }
};
```

Comment: That totally depends on what you want to achieve. Is the "current date" the date at the time of the function call, or at the time of the (one-off) construction of the variable? Only you can know your own requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are correct in saying that variables should be declared locally when possible, as this can remove potential conflicts between different variables in the future (this becomes a problem especially in large projects with thousands of lines of code).

I would define `QString currentDate` outside your `function`s, and then supply it as an argument to `function_1()` and `function_2()`, as this will remove the repetition of code.

Answer (score 1):

If `currentDate` will be calculated once in the constructor, then the value will be unchanged for the lifetime of the variable.

In this case if the variable will not live across days, then no problem.

But if it will (for example 23:59:59 -> 00:00:00) then the correct way would be to declare a function:

```
 QString currentDate() 
 {
    return QDate::currentDate().toString("MM/dd/yy");
 }
```

Consider making this function static as it doesn't call any functions and variables from the class.